# Matlab: Using imhist() with equal-sized bins

Tags: matlab, grayscale

I use both Matlab and OpenCV to produce Grayscale histogram, divided into 10 bins.

In OpenCV, each bin has equal range (i.e. [0,25], [26,51], [52,77], ...).

However, in Matlab, the bin sizes are not equal (I guess it's related to some theory about different sensitivity to intensity changes between lower and higher values).

These different results make big trouble for me.

Is there an option to use `calcHist` with equal bin sizes? (Of course except for the option of implementing it myself...)

Comment: doesn't `calcHist` have an optional `edges` input?

Comment: It might have, but I don't want to specify each of them manually. I sometimes change the number of bins..

Comment: I don't get it. I tried `imhist(img, 10)` and I actually see equal-sized bin?

Comment: Can you show a sample code? Both matlab and opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question with a self-implemented function:

```
function h = fixedSizeBinnedHist(grayImg, numBins)
    binSize = 256 / numBins;
    binnedImg = floor(double(grayImg) / binSize);
    maxVal = max(binnedImg(:));
    numLeadingZeros = min(binnedImg(:));        
    numTrailingZeros = numBins - maxVal - 1;
    % First, computing histogram for the existing range
    h = hist(double(binnedImg(:)), maxVal - numLeadingZeros + 1);
    leading = zeros(1, numLeadingZeros);
    trailing = zeros(1, numTrailingZeros);
    % Finally attaching needed zeros in both sides, so the histogram is in the requested size
    h = [leading h trailing];
end
```